# Delphi/Lazarus | Is there a way to simplify global OnMouseEnter event handling?

Tags: delphi, event-handling, portability, lazarus, simplify

### Problem

I would like to simplify the following code in **Delphi XE6 on Windows**, which becomes unmaintainable as I am adding more and more types of components.

**Portability note:** I would like to use the same code later in **Lazarus 2.0.2 on Linux** with little to no change, so the Windows message handling is out of the question.

The problem is, I can't seem to find a way to assign the OnMouseEnter event handler to all components on the whole Form.

I tried all I could including various classes common in their object tree. The OnMouseEnter event seems to be nowhere in the common ground.

The event handler itself contains just one command (procedure = void function), and it will have no more, maybe this could simplify the whole problem?

As you can see below, at this moment I need to add each type of component (currently only TLabel, TButton, and TEdit) to the for-loop.

---

```pascal
procedure TFormMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
    I: Integer;
begin
    for I := 0 to FormMain.ComponentCount - 1 do
    begin
        if FormMain.Components[I] is TLabel then
        begin
            (FormMain.Components[I] as TLabel).OnMouseEnter
                := @CustomGenericMouseEnter;
        end;
        if FormMain.Components[I] is TButton then
        begin
            (FormMain.Components[I] as TButton).OnMouseEnter
                := @CustomGenericMouseEnter;
        end;
        if FormMain.Components[I] is TEdit then
        begin
            (FormMain.Components[I] as TEdit).OnMouseEnter
                := @CustomGenericMouseEnter;
        end;
    end;
end;

procedure TFormMain.CustomGenericMouseEnter(Sender: TObject);
begin
    SingleCustomProcedure; // no arguments, nor return value
end;
```

---

### Motivation

I am programming a **color picker** application and thus want to show the user the mouse coordinates.

I have a Polling timer in there, I don't want to add more code, than necessary, so I hope this is self-explanatory:

```pascal
procedure TFormMain.TimerMousePollTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
    if MousePosChanged then
    begin
        LabelEdit_MousePosX.Text := MousePosX.ToString;
        LabelEdit_MousePosY.Text := MousePosY.ToString;
    end;
end;
```

Further, I do have **OnMouseLeave** implemented.

Comment: Why not simply assign a handler to `TApplication(Events).OnMessage` and handle `WM_MOUSEMOVE` messages? You can retrieve the `TControl` under the mouse by using the [`GetMessagePos()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmessagepos) and [`FindDragTarget()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.FindDragTarget) functions.

Comment: @RemyLebeau For future readers I have clarified why the Windows message handlig is out of the question, see Portability note, please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The OnMouseEnter event seems to be nowhere in the common ground.

Actually, it is. `OnMouseEnter` is a member of `TControl`, which all visual controls derive from, but most controls do not promote it to `published`. However, since it is declared as `protected`, you can use an accessor class to reach it on any control, eg:

```
type
  TControlAccess = class(TControl)
  end;

procedure TFormMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
  Comp: TComponent;
begin
  for I := 0 to ComponentCount - 1 do
  begin
    Comp := Components[I];
    if Comp is TControl then
      TControlAccess(Comp).OnMouseEnter := CustomGenericMouseEnter;
  end;
end;
```

This works because `TControlAccess` gains access to all of `TControl`'s protected members, and the unit that declares `TControlAccess` has access to all of `TControlAccess`'s protected members.

On the other hand, `OnMouseEnter` is initially `protected` so controls can decide whether they want to expose access to it. If you want to respect that decision and only set it for controls that have promoted it, you can use RTTI for that, eg:

```
uses
  ..., TypInfo;

procedure TFormMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
  Comp: TComponent;
  Prop: PPropInfo;
  M: TMethod;
begin
  TNotifyEvent(M) := CustomGenericMouseEnter;
  for I := 0 to ComponentCount - 1 do
  begin
    Comp := Components[I];
    if not (Comp is TControl) then Continue;
    Prop := GetPropInfo(Comp, 'OnMouseEnter', [tkMethod]);
    if Prop <> nil then
      SetMethodProp(Comp, Prop, M);
  end;
end;
```

Alternatively (Delphi 2010+ only):

```
uses
  ..., System.Rtti;

procedure TFormMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
  Ctx: TRttiContext;
  Comp: TComponent;
  Prop: TRttiProperty;
  V: TValue;
begin
  V := TValue.From<TNotifyEvent>(CustomGenericMouseEnter);
  for I := 0 to ComponentCount - 1 do
  begin
    Comp := Components[I];
    if not (Comp is TControl) then Continue;
    Ctx.GetType(Comp.ClassType).GetProperty('OnMouseEnter');
    if (Prop <> nil) and (Prop.Visibility in [TMemberVisibility.mvPublic, TMemberVisibility.mvPublished]) then
      Prop.SetValue(Comp, V);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: For first snippet, Components/ComponentCount -> Controls/ControlCount

Comment: @SertacAkyuz using `Components[]`, you get access to all controls created at design time in a single list. Using `Controls[]`, you have to recursively drill through the parent/child tree.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. My issue was the possible invalid typecast.